# Trigger AJAX single function for two buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am using 2 buttons to open two separate php pages but I would like to use one function to trigger both the buttons. The AJAX function that gets triggered should check which button was pressed and then open the php page associated with it. Such that "Export Page 1" should open Page 1.php and "Export Page 2" should open Page 2.php.
I am able to open one php page with my AJAX function. Now how do I check which button was pressed so I could open the right php page. How do I achieve this?

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div> 
        <input type ="submit" name="login" id="login" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;" class= "btn btn-primary" value="Export Page 1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"/>

        <input type ="submit" name="login" id="login" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;" class= "btn btn-primary" value="Export Page 2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"/>

  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />
                <br/>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                <br/>
                <button type="button" name="login_button" id="login_button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

<script>
    $('#login_button').click(function(){
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        if(username != '' && password != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"Login.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{username:username, password:password},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data == 'No')
                    {
                        alert("Wrong Data");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#loginModal').hide();
                        window.open("Page 1.php"); //For page 1
                        // OR window.open("Page 2.php"); //For page 2
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Both fields are requried");
        }
        
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Your html doesn't include an `id=login_button` to match `$("#login_button")` - assuming you mean `$("#login")` - this will only work for the first button because **IDs must be unique**.  Give your buttons different IDs then use `if (this.id ==` to determine which one was clicked.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was not needed. I shall add it now.

Comment: Going off of what freedomn-m said, your onclick event is calling for something with the id "login_button" when your two buttons are clicked. Make sure the ID you are calling in your jQuery is also the same id as your button. I.e. $("#login")

Comment: Okay thank you. I have added the #loginModal

Comment: Because you're auto-opening the modal, there's a separation from open-dialog with button1/2 to click login on modal, so they're not related.  You'll need to store on the modal/global/etc which button was used to open the modal when it's opened so that you can use that value when you actually login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because IDs must be unique, give each button a different ID

```
<input type="submit" id="login1" value="Export Page 1"...
<input type="submit" id="login2" value="Export Page 2"...
```

you can then give both buttons the same event - this would also work if you gave them both the same class and did the event on that class.

Within the event, store the button id somewhere where it can be picked up later by the modal's login button.

Because you're auto-opening the modal, there's a separation from open-dialog with button1/2 to click login on modal, so they're not related. You'll need to store on the modal/global/etc which button was used to open the modal when it's opened so that you can use that value when you actually login.

Let's store it on the modal's login_button:

```
$("#login1,#login2").click(function() {
    $("#login_button").data("source_button", this.id);
});
```

where this.id will be login1 or login2.

Now when the login_button is clicked, we can see which button it was:

```
$("#login_button").click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: { username: username, password: password },
    success: function(data) {

      $('#loginModal').hide();

      var source_button = $("#login_button").data("source_button");
      if (source_button == "login1")
        window.open("Page 1.php");
      else
        window.open("Page 2.php");
    }
  });
});
```

---

To make this a little more usable (and less maintenance-heavy), you can make some small changes:

- don't use an ID on the page button
- code the destination page onto the page button

```
<input type="submit" class="pagelogin" data-page='page1.php' value="Export Page 1"...
<input type="submit" class="pagelogin" data-page='page2.php' value="Export Page 2"...
```

then

```
$(".pagelogin").click(function() {
    $("#login_button").data("page", $(this).data("page"));
});
```

and in the callback

```
success: function() {
  
  $('#loginModal').hide();
  window.open($("#login_button").data("page"))

}
```

so when you want to add page3 etc you just add a new input with no code changes and keeps the separation of data (the page1.php) from the code (the js), which is always a goodthing(tm).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the detailed explanation :) I am using your code with ```var source_button = $("#login_button").data("source_button");``` and I also changed the ID for both but unfortunately the page is not at all opening. There are no errors either.

Comment: Make sure you only have one id=login_button (you already had 2 with id=login).  What does `console.log($("[id=login_button]").length)` give you?

Comment: The console outputs as `1`. I am also doing it this way ```var source_button = $("#login_button").data("source_button");
if (source_button == "login1"){ window.open("Page1.php"); } else if (source_button == "login2") { window.open("Page2.php"); }
```

Comment: Looks like it is not able to detect which source_button it is. The console log for source_button is (index):113 undefined

Comment: what does this give you?  `var source_button = $("#login_button").data("source_button"); console.log("source_button")`   Looks like you're not storing it on the login_button.  Did you add the `$("#login1,#login2").click(function() {` and check that it's being called (add a console.log/alert/breakpoint inside)

Comment: Thanks alot! It was not saving in source_button as that function was declared after my AJAX function. Now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions for that:

```js
function openPage(page) {
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        data:{
            username:username, password:password
        },
        success:function(data) {
            $('#loginModal').hide();
            
            window.open(page); 
        }   
    });
}
```

In the html:

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="openPage('Page 1.php')" name="login" id="login" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;" class= "btn btn-primary" value="Export Page 1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"  />
<input type="submit" onclick="openPage('Page 2.php')" name="login" id="login" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;" class= "btn btn-primary" value="Export Page 2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" />
```

Comment: Thank you but I am already using a function which is basically login to check if the details are right and only then the page is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) aswell
make a single function for both buttons use the event parameter to extract the `data-page` out of the clicked element and pass through it

```js
function submitButtonHandler(e) {
  var targetPage = e.target.dataset.page;
  console.log('Target is ' + targetPage);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', submitButtonHandler);
  document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', submitButtonHandler);
});
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Login 1" data-page="Page 1" id="button1">
<input type="submit" value="Login 2" data-page="Page 2" id="button2">
```

Comment: Please see updated question - the "login" button opens a modal, then submitlogin is from that modal.  Would have helped if OP had included that up front.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I have updated it now. I am using ```$('#login_button').click(function(){```. So how do I reference your ```data-page``` in my function?

Comment: you can use it, as i edited it, instead of writing to console, you can also save it in an unique element from there and call it from there later again, the idea is still the same